# Strange line artifact in a mesh

Tags: artifacts

After merge the leg points with the body points I get this strange line in the intersection. Why?

This is the mesh:

[image]

This is the effect with shade flat:

[image: shade flat]

And this is the effect with shade smooth:

[image]

[This is the file for review it](https://pasteall.org/blend/687c7019ad4549aebbe2fd22af5cc7a2).

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fully connected face "inside" your leg - meshes like this are known as *Non-Manifold* (they have stuff in them that shouldn't be there) - Blender works best with *manifold* geometry ("hollow" meshes) - delete the offending (interior) face and you're good:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have an internal face - that is, a face that runs inside your mesh from the verts seen on the outside.

You can see this if you go into X-Ray mode:

[image]

Delete it and you'll be fine.