# Why my cup object's seam become like this?

Tags: mesh

I have *Mark Seam* my beer mug and use it to make the beer mug's holder. But the result become like this[image]

Even though i *Remove Double* it, the seam is still there and worst of it, the top of beer mug split open like in the picture.

How to fix this? Here's the blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/bda4874634c544c2bc84fb0c99fa5392

Comment: Looks like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261843/strange-line-artifact-in-a-mesh) is your problem.

Comment: @Hulifier sorry for late reply, but as i check my object, there is no non manifold geometry that has been mentioned in the answer you give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's interior faces in your mesh:

[image: Interior faces]

I don't know if that option exists in the version you're using, but you can select interior faces this way:

- **Select** -> **Select All by Trait** -> **Interior Faces**

[image: select interior faces]

Comment: I have follow your instruction, but i can't see the face through like the way you do it in your picture

Comment: I Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces, but i can't see it through the faces

Comment: Go into x-ray mode (ALT-Z) to see the faces, but you only need to X > Delete Faces to get rid of them them once they've been selected. That will get rid of the line up the side. Not sure about the gap in the top rim though. That's a seperate issue.

Comment: @JohnEason There is no x-ray mode in my blender version of 2.79, only wireframe and when i check the seam line, i grab the faces inside the mesh's seam line and when i select linked the faces, all of object's vertices is also selected.

Comment: Ah ok. I haven't had 2.79 on my PC for several years so didn't realise that x-ray wasn't available on that. Wireframe mode should show the faces though if you view from the side and zoom in. Selecting Linked will indeed select all the faces of the object so don't do that. Just using @hulifier's method to select them and immediately deleting them even if you can't actually see them should do the trick. The gap in the rim is because there are faces missing but it looks as if you've already applied a previous subdiv modifier so that would be very difficulty to correct.